# How to replace jquery variable values with php array values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I am working with php and i want to change value of dropdown using jquery, i want to pass php array into jquery variable(make dynamic dropdown value)
Right now i am getting array($data) in following format

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [UserId] => 8
            [name] => web1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [UserId] => 9
            [name] => web2
        )
)
```

And here is my script which is showing static "dropdown" values,but i want to pass php array (name) values to dropdown so i can make dynamic dropdown

```
<script>
    var newOptions = {
    "Select your user":"",
    "Option 1":"option-1",
    "Option 2":"option-2"
    };

    var $el = $('#acf-field_628e17fc947e4');
    $el.html(' ');
    $.each(newOptions, function(key, value) {
    $el.append($("<option></option>")
    .attr("value", value).text(key));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Change only last line : $el.append('<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>')

Comment: @VinodPatidar: i want to use PHP array values(name) instead of static values (newOptions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var newOptions = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
```

and then change your append line to this and you are good to go

```
$el.append('<option value="'+ value.UserId +'">'+ value.name +'</option>');
```

Working snippet:

```js
var newOptions = [{"UserId":8,"name":"web1"},{"UserId":9,"name":"web2"}];
var $el = $('#acf-field_628e17fc947e4');
$el.html(' ');
$el.append('<option value="">Select your user</option>');
$.each(newOptions, function(key, value) {
    $el.append('<option value="'+ value.UserId +'">'+ value.name +'</option>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="acf-field_628e17fc947e4"></select>
```

Note: to add select option, add it in array like this:

```
array_unshift($array , ['UserId'=>'',"name":"name":"web1"]);
```

And then remove this line : `$el.append('<option value="">Select your user</option>');`

Answer (score 0):

You have an array to pass from PHP to JS so you can use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) like: (The example below is dynamic)

```
<?php
    $phpArray = array(
        0 => "Mon", 
        1 => "Tue", 
        2 => "Wed", 
        3 => "Thu",
        4 => "Fri", 
        5 => "Sat",
        6 => "Sun",
    )
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var jArray = <?php echo json_encode($phpArray); ?>;

    for(var i=0; i<jArray.length; i++){
        alert(jArray[i]);
    }

 </script>
```

Comment: i can but how i can show using loop because this can be multiple values in dropdown

Comment: as i mentioned dropdown values are multiple so how i can display multiple dynamic values ?